# Save excel file using savefiledialog class in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I need to create and save a Excel file without inform in the code the path and file name. So I can use the savefiledialog to show the save box to input the path and file name, but I can´t use it correctly.
I tried to use the worksheet.saveas but this class doesn´t show the save box to input the path and file name.
How can I save a excel file with that save box?

Comment: Is it a WinForms or WPF application? Or are you trying to do it in a C# Library / Console App?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic mechanic of it is this:

```
public void SaveExcelWorkBook()
{
   OpenFileDialog openDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
   openDlg.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
   openDlg.ShowDialog();
   string path = openDlg.FileName;

   if (openDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      try
      {
         Application excelApp = new Application();
         Workbook workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
         Worksheet workSheet = (Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets[1];

         // Do your work here inbetween the declaration of your workbook/worksheet  
         // and the save action below.

         workBook.SaveAs(/*path to save it to*/);  // NOTE: You can use 'Save()' or 'SaveAs()'
         workBook.Close(); 
      }

      catch (Exception ex)
      {
      }
   }
}
```

I think I should also mention that Interop objects are *unmanaged* so, you will want to make sure that you are releasing them after calling `.Close()`.  Here is an example:

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBook);
```

There are two fantastic tutorials for using Excel [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects).  Good luck!

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your answer, but I want that the user input the path and the name of the file. So it´s needs to show that box like when you click in the "save as" button in the Excel program.

Comment: That's a `FileDialog`.  C# has a [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog(v=vs.110).aspx) for that too.

Comment: I have edited my answer to incorporate what you asked about in comments.