# Calling the (Save As) dialogue box after opening an Excel file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms, office-interop

After processing, my application automatically opens an Excel file. When you open an Excel file, the Save As dialogue box must also be opened. Is it possible ?

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Save AS Dialoge box calling.

Comment: Yes it is !
Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824123/save-excel-file-using-savefiledialog-class-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You didn't post any code. What you posted isn't even executable code, just a namespace alias. Any method available in VBA is also available through interop. Have you tried actually calling `SaveAs`  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Excel's the [Application.FileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.filedialog) property (method in C#) to get the required dialog and then display to a user, for example, the following VBA sample shows how to do that:

```
Sub SaveWorkbook()
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            sPath = .SelectedItems(1)
            ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sPath & Application.PathSeparator & "Copy of " & ThisWorkbook.Name
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Also you may consider using the .net base class libraries that provide the built-in class for that:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"  ;
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;
 
if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   string path = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
}
```

See [SaveFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) for more information.